# Arrays in ARFF files

Tags: python, json, arff

Given an array of data from a .json file, i.e.:

```
"data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How would you then insert that data into a an arff file?
Would I have to define some NOMINAL type, and if so how would a define the type.

```
@ATTRIBUTE data        __DEFINE__
```

Or would I use the INTEGER type? 
If neither, then how so?

Also, for creating the arff file I am using python3.4 and its JSON library so I can do:

```
json_file = json.loads(curl(url), encoding='iso-8859-i')
file = open("file.arff", 'w')
file.write("@ATTRIBUTE data  __DEFINE__\n @ATTRIBUTE class {C1, C2}")
file.write("{0},C1".format(json["data"]))
```